# Access two way binding (model) from template into a directive, Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

having this case:

```
 <sample ng-repeat="item in items" id="item.value"></sample>
```

and this directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
      restrict : 'E',
      scope : {
        id : '='
      },
     template : '<div id='THE ID VALUE'>something</div>'
   }
}
```

How do I access to the item.value value into the template key???

here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jomame/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like usual:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
      restrict : 'E',
      scope : {
        id : '='
      },
     template : '<div id="{{id}}">something</div>'
   }
}
```

And your id is not being replaced, should be as follows:

```
 <sample ng-repeat="item in items" id="{{item.value}}"></sample>
```

Comment: yes I thougth about it, however, it pass item.id instead of the value added in the ng-repeat

Comment: kind of not working neither, could you please take a look at http://jsbin.com/jomame/edit?html,js,console,output ??? thanks for ur help